# TextBox inside GridView validation

Tags: .net, asp.net, regex, validation, gridview

This is my code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>' Width="88px" CausesValidation="True" />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid email id!" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

when i am clicking next button required field validation is not causing validation and its not showing any error and page is re-directing on next page.

Please help me.

Comment: I have text box in gridview and i want to validate email id if txtEmail is blank then it show error else page redirect to next page..

Comment: Does incorrect text cause RegEx validator to validate?

Comment: You have a typo in your code: "ControlToValidate="txtEmail />". (No trailing quote mark after id)

Comment: post complete code. aspx and code behind. we will defiantly help you more...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the following code.

[image]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default4.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">

                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>' Width="88px"
                            CausesValidation="True" />
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid email id!"
                            ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
                            ControlToValidate="txtEmail" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CausesValidation="true" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default4 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var items = new[] {
                new { FirstName = "Name1",Email="sa@gmail.com" },
                new { FirstName = "Name2",Email="test@gmail.com" },
                new { FirstName = "Name3",Email="test@gmail.com" }};

        grd.DataSource = items;

        grd.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There might be the problem with the Validation group, you can check that.

Secondly you need to set the `CausesValidation="true"` in your button control.

Plus your email regular expression is not correct as well.

```
\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)* // yours
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)* // correct one
```

Comment: the only difference between this 2 regex is that it will allow apostrophes in the part before the @

Comment: but regular expression is causing the error only require field is not causing the error when i am clicking on go next page button..

Comment: @Ansari; try to change the expression.

Comment: i changed the expression but required field is not working yet

Comment: did your button have validation group property ?

Comment: @Ansari; can you set CausesValidation="true" to your button control.

Comment: can you set CausesValidation="true" to your button control.

Comment: you know validation is causing, but when i am clicking on btn next require field validation is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add [Script Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163354.aspx) to your project ?

If so, nothing wrong with your validation code.

Just an idea, maybe you should add to validation controls `EnableClientScript="false"`

Comment: i am not using any ajax tool, so its not mandatory to add script manager

Comment: after EnableClientScript="false" require field is not working

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check if **CausesValidation** is enabled for the **next** button you are clicking.

Also in addition try setting the **InitialValue-""** for the Required field validator

**EDIT**

Try modifying your code to adding the client script such as

```
button.Attributes.Add("onclick","return methodname");
```

Comment: ya its enable but require field is not causing validation.

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" Text="Next" class="next btn" onclick="btnNext_Click"  OnClientClick="getAuthors('tblAuthors')"/>

Comment: my btnnext is not causing validation :( :( i am stuck in this only

Comment: I believe the ClientClick is causing the problem can you register it via script block from the code behind

Comment: my validation is working when i am moving one filed to an other through tab btn of keyboard but as btnnext is clicked validation is not working

Comment: btnOne.Attributes.Add("onclick","return JavascriptMethod"); in this fasion

Comment: Did you try adding the attribute as suggested, Did that work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function ValidateText(i) 
{
    if(i.value.length>0) 
    {
    i.value = i.value.replace(/[^\d]+/g, ''); 
    }
}

</script>

<asp:TemplateField >
      <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeyup ="ValidateText(this);"></asp:TextBox>
     </ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>  

<    /asp:TemplateField>
```