# How to create a pop up error message when gridview encounters 'does not allow nulls' server error?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I've been looking on the interwebs for some set of instructions that can show me how I can create a popup error message when one attempts to insert a null value on a gridview when it's set to not allow nulls in the database.  I'm pretty sure I've been looking up the wrong terminology as I haven't seen anything that resembles what I'm looking for.

Basically what I need is an error popup/window to appear, when a field on a gridview is supposed to have a value entered and is left blank, stating 'You're supposed to fill in blah blah blah...'

I tried using NullDisplayText but that doesn't seem to work for what I need.  I've searched for various searches for gridview null popup.  I've even searched on Javascript solutions but with no luck.

Am I just searching for the wrong terms or has no one even attempted this at all?

Comment: Are they adding data at this point?  For example I want to add or edit a row, but if I leave a column blank you want to pop a message?

Comment: Yeah pretty much.  I just want to have some reminder that they need to fill out specific fields if they are manditory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching the 'net for "RequiredFieldvalidator Gridview". Here's a similar SO question (albeit w/o the popup aspect):
[TextBox inside GridView validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775856/textbox-inside-gridview-validation)

Would've made this a comment but my rep is not high enough.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  That sets me in the right direction.  Gave you some more rep too.  :-)